# Записи wordpress

Tags: wordpress, запись

Здравствуйте, у меня есть страница index.php и в ней есть 4 раздела мне нужно чтобы каждый раздел имел свои записи и если я буду добавлять записи через админку чтобы одна запись не добавлялась во все 4 разделала, а только в один единственный, который я выберу, как этом можно реализовать?

Comment: Создайте 4 рубрики, назначьте каждому разделу на index.php свою рубрику и распределите свои записи по рубрикам.

Comment: Страницы index.php быть не может.. А всё остальное - стандартный функционал ВП

Comment: @ Gleb Kemarsky спасибо, вы мне помогли, вопрос закрыт